# Easily access fields in Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :default_permission
end

class DefaultPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :permission
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :default_permissions
end
```

Which is the easiest way to get default permissions for a specific user?

Using a scope? Or can I do something like user.defaultpermission.permissions ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data correctly stored, this will work:

```
user.default_permission.permissions
```

this seems complicated thought -- it might be a sign your design is flawed.

Comment: Someone suggested to use has_and_belongs_to_many but how can I do that? For this example I can do that. But what If I had User, Permission and Application model. Can I create a table with 3 columns using has_and_belongs_to_many?

Comment: what does default_permission do?

Comment: it's some predefined attributes that are store when a user is created. But at the future when a user tries to install an Application it will accept some other permissions for those apps.

Comment: Are the predefined attributes going to vary per user?  If so, could you elaborate further on the behavior?  If not, then you can scrap `default_permission` as a model and initialize a user **and** a permission, using predefined attributes for that permission.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of contradictory
You have a has_one default_permission defined but you are asking how to get all the default_permissions for a user?
Whether or not I have misunderstood your question it is quite clear that you have a small design flaw
If you want to get all permissions for a user then you need to define a has_many permissions with the appropriate user_id on the permission table
or
If you want all the default permissions then you need to change the has_one default permission to a has_many default permissions

Personally I would use roles rather than permissions and define the permissions as business logic methods on either the roles class or the person class whichever best suits your requirements

That way you can define can_do_something? methods on the user class
thus a person or user or whatever can have one or many roles and the user class can_do_something? methods look at the roles and decide whether to return true or false